# findall/3 returns an empty list instead of solutions

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog, prolog-findall

I use GNU Prolog to solve a problem. I have defined the following predicate :

```
% P is the product of X and Y
produit(X,Y,P) :- 
    between(2,200,X),
    between(2,200,Y),
    X #<# Y,
    X*Y #=# P.

% S is the sum of X and Y 
somme(X,Y,S) :-
    between(2,200,X),
    between(2,200,Y),
    X #<# Y,
    X+Y #=# S.

%je ne peux pas deviner
clue_one(X,Y) :-
    produit(X,Y,P),
    XX*YY #=# P,
    XX #\=# X,
    XX #\=# 1,
    YY #\=# 1,
    XX #\=# Y.

%je le savais
clue_two(S) :-
    forall(somme(X,Y,S), clue_one(X,Y)).
```

Prolog says that `clue_two(17)` is true but when I try  `findall(S, clue_two(S), L)` , GNU Prolog returns the empty list. Why?

Comment: `findall/3` shows no solutions because `clue_two(S)` finds no solutions, which is explained by Paulo's answer.

Comment: You are mixing here contraints and more traditional programming style in one program. Not sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forall/2` de facto standard predicate is equivalent to:

```
forall(Generator, Test) :-
    \+ (Generator, \+ Test).
```

Due to the use of negation, no bindings resulting from the calls to either `Generator` or `Test` are returned.